# View.bottom constraint is not working when I start app holding phone sideways

Tags: swift, xcode, rotation, constraints

I have a tableview that is set to view.bottom and when I start the app holding my phone sideways, Its bottom constraint is at about half screen. I assume Its because the view constraints change with phone rotation.

In app delegate I set self.rotation = .portrait but it still treats it as sideways.

I need view.bottomAchor to still be the bottom of the phone despite the phone being sideways

(I need it to act like the phone is vertical even if its not)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set your constraints again when ViewController is about to rotate via this method: -

```
  override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        // TODO: -  Set your constraints
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

constraint should not change on rotating phone, select your bottom constraint and set first item from **SAFE AREA** to **SUPERVIEW**

[image]